# reading datagridview row and creating folders

Tags: c#

I  have  exported a csv file to datagridview and now want to create new folder based on column text in datagridview.
I need to create new folders like MEE814g,AF11JYW,PY10HNN,GJ03XLB base on particular column.
no error or nothing it just not creating any folders. how to read a column in datagridview which has no headers and create folders.

```
Addenbrooks Hospital    MEE814G 2014-03-11 07:32:35 2014-03-11 07:35:01 1
Addenbrooks Hospital    AF11JYW 2014-03-11 10:02:16 2014-03-11 10:04:13 1
Addenbrooks Hospital    PY10HNN 2014-03-11 10:05:33 2014-03-11 10:07:26 1
Addenbrooks Hospital    GJ03XLB 2014-03-11 10:11:14 2014-03-11 10:13:15 1
```

this is my code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

string[] all_txt = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\IT-Administrator\\Desktop\\fg\\fg.csv").Split('\n');
int count_row = 0;
foreach (string row in all_txt)
{
   string[] data = row.Split(';');
   if (count_row == 0)
   {
      foreach (string header in data)
      {
         ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(header);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(data);
   }
   count_row++;


}



foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\\smrithi\\hhh\" + fields);
   ////
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\smrithi\hhh\" + row.Cells[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: can you debug and see whetehr it enters into foreach loop or not?

Answer (score 0):

if the number of imported columns in the datagrid remains the same you can just use an index to access it as such

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var columnValue = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\\smrithi\\hhh\" + columnValue);
    }
```

I hope this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I get this error on first line of your code.. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the directory like this

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"I:\\smrithi\\hhh\" + data.GetValue(0).ToString()))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"I:\\smrithi\\hhh\" + data.GetValue(0).ToString() );
                }
```

I dont know that  MEE814g,AF11JYW,PY10HNN,GJ03XLB this all values are in which index. 
    Your data variable consist of all the information. then from that data variable you can retrieve the specific value like this data.GetValue(0).ToString(). 
    I hope this will solve your issue